# jQuery .blur .focus not Working in Test

Tags: javascript, jquery

When writing a jasmine test, it appears that jQuery doesn't recognize that an input has focus. When changing between the two input elements, the alert isn't shown and when clicking out of the inputs without focusing the other one the alert is shown. However, by using `.focus` and `.blur` in my test code, I can't get the desired behaviour. It always thinks that none of them are focused. Also without calling `.triggerHandler`, the blur handler isn't invoked at all.

The inputs are visible and are attached to the DOM.

```
var $inputs = $("input");
function blurTimeout() {
  if (!$inputs.is(":focus")) {
    alert("Nothing's focused");
  }
}

function blur() {
  setTimeout(blurTimeout, 0);
}

function main() {
  $inputs.on("blur", blur);
}
$(main);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjgmrgkL/1/)

**Edit**
It would appear that calling `$inputs.first().focus()` to focus one of the inputs, then `alert($inputs.first().is(":focus"))` alerts `false`.

```
var $input = $inputs.first();
$input.focus();
alert(!!$input.is("focus")); // -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

The events and handlers seem to fire just fine. The problem is the logic. When any of the inputs has focus `!$inputs.is(':focus')` always returns `false`. You can resolve that by replacing:

```
!$inputs.is(':focus')
```

With:

```
$inputs.filter(':focus').length
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sjgmrgkL/3/)

Comment: Huh. Very odd, because this works in the project code (same event setup, same condition logic). Thank you, I will see if this fixes it tomorrow.

Comment: After trying your solution I realized that I might not have explained the issue correctly. I want `!$inputs.is(":focus")` to return `false` when any of the inputs has focus.

Comment: And that's what you're getting. So where is the problem then? ..... **But, more importantly, what behavior are you looking for when focus moves from one input to the other input?**

Comment: I'm trying to write a test to prove that the code works. Using the jQuery `.focus` and `.blur` functions isn't allowing me to do this (it doesn't focus/blur the elements).

Comment: But, more importantly, what behavior are you looking for when focus moves from one input to the other input?

Comment: For that condition to evaluate to `false` and not execute the if block. It is currently doing that, as intended. I just can't prove it in a test.

Comment: I understand. You are not able to replicate here the issue you're having in you application, right? Just a quick note: `$inputs.is(':focus')` is rather ambiguous - which of the inputs are you trying to check for focus on - **jQuery checks the first - is that your intention?**. Although it might not help resolve your issue, I would suggest using a more concise test.

Comment: I assumed that it would check all the elements in the collection. Now it's even odder as to why it works outside of a test. After going over the code with a co-worker we decided to change it to manually iterate over the elements and check against `document.activeElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the changed code. Testing now works as intended and the original behaviour is kept.

```
var $inputs = $("input");
function blurTimeout() {
    var index = $inputs.length;
    while(index--){
        if($inputs[index] === document.activeElement){
            return;
        }
    }
    alert("Nothing's focused");
}

function blur() {
    setTimeout(blurTimeout, 0);
}

function main() {
    $inputs.on("blur", blur);
}
$(main);
```